# AWK printing columns based on column number and pattern match condition

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I need to reformat the output of the following command using awk for static and dynamic column numbers:

```
 ps -eopid,lstart,cmd | grep java |grep -v grep
```

following would be sample input to the awk command:

```
17524 Wed May  9 08:50:37 2018 /opt/java/latest/bin/java -client -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/projects/domainName/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Xverify:none -da -Dplatform.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server -Ddomain.home=/projects/domainName -Does.client.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/oesclient -Doracle.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/oesclient -Doracle.security.jps.config=/projects/mydomain/config/oeswlssmconfig/AdminServer/jps-config.xml -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/app/oracle/wls1036/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/app/oracle/wls1036/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath weblogic.Server
```

Sample Output:

```
24519 Wed May 9 23:50:09 2018 -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer
```

Issue: I am able to print the value of initial PID, Startup date and time based on the column number using awk but the last value's column number can be different in cases(eg: column9 in one output and column 17 in another). How can i print the last value searching corresponding column number containing keyword "-Dweblogic.Name=" and add to the existing output. Combining output for column numbers and column search is throwing exception. 
Any easier way to format this output is welcome too using (sed,grep,cut etc).

Comment: The last column in awk is `$NF`. Other than that, I cannot tell what you want to do because your sample input bears no relation to your sample output.

Comment: @Nick the output is based on fixed columns ( 24519 Wed May 9 23:50:09 2018) and a not fixed column containing keyword "-Dweblogic.Name=" . i.e (-Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer)

Comment: Take a look at `pgrep`

Answer (score 0):

to get column, use a loop

```
| awk '{for(i=NF;i>1;i--) 
     if ( $i ~ /-Dweblogic.name/ ) { wln=$i; break } ;
     printf "... %s ...",wln}'
```

where

- `NF` is represent the number of fields
- `for( )` construct will loop from end of line to begin
- `$i ~ /-Dweblogic.name/` match -Dweblogic.name=admin1 , -Dweblogic.name=otheradmin (you may want /^-D/ to not match yourself)

may I sugest you drop `grep java | grep -v grep` to `grep [j]ava` witch will not grep itslef (and amaze coworker), or

```
| awk '/java/ {...} '
```

or, to have a mainimal number of arg :

```
| awk '/java/ && NF>10 { ... }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can search Dweblogic with grep and after with sed

```
search="-Dweblogic.Name="
ps -eopid,lstart,cmd | \
grep "java.*$search" | \
sed -E 's#([^/]* )/.*('"$search"'[^ ]*).*#\1\2#'
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work when i use it in ssh script block.Is there any escape sequence to help it work. > ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -t myuserid@$ip << EOF

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .words; put "@a[0..5] @a.grep(/^ \-Dweblogic\.Name\= /)" if .words > 6;'
```

Sample Input:

```
17524 Wed May  9 08:50:37 2018 /opt/java/latest/bin/java -client -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/projects/domainName/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Xverify:none -da -Dplatform.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/wlserver_10.3/server -Ddomain.home=/projects/domainName -Does.client.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/oesclient -Doracle.home=/app/oracle/wls1036/oesclient -Doracle.security.jps.config=/projects/mydomain/config/oeswlssmconfig/AdminServer/jps-config.xml -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/app/oracle/wls1036/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/app/oracle/wls1036/patch_ocp371/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath weblogic.Server
```

Sample Output:

```
17524 Wed May 9 08:50:37 2018 -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer
```

Briefly, `-ne` linewise input is broken into whitespace-separated `words`, and assigned to `@a` array. Then the initial 6 columns (words `[0..5]`) are out`put`, followed by `grep`ping for full words that match the `/^ \-Dweblogic\.Name\= /` regex (also can be written: `/^ "-Dweblogic.Name=" /` ).

The code above handles short/blank lines in the input, however it prints the first 6 columns (PID and timestamp) even if `/^ \-Dweblogic\.Name\= /` isn't found. Much better to use the code below, which overcomes this issue using Raku's `$_` topic variable:

```perl
raku -ne 'my @a = .words; $_ = @a.grep(/^ \-Dweblogic\.Name\= /); put "@a[0..5] $_" if $_;'
```

https://raku.org